# Copying mp3 files to an iPad or iPod without iTunes? (from Windows, Mac or Linux)

Tags: itunes, ipad, ipod, file-transfer, mp3

I'm looking for a way to copy a set of mp3 files to my iPad, and/or perhaps even my old iPod.

A long time ago I used to do this with iTunes which I strongly dislike, but it seemed to be the only option at the time. Recently tried again but couldn't get it to work anymore, and since Apple is gonna phase out iTunes, I'm wondering is there an alternative way?

Preferably I'm looking for a universal solution to do this from Windows, as well as macOs, as well as Linux. But either one of them would already be great.

Comment: iTunes is the way to go, also in the future. If you are looking for help in getting your current iTunes problems resolved, please ask a new question describing what kind of problems you run into. Please make sure to include iOS, macOS and iTunes version as well.

Comment: @nohillside Thanks but no I would really prefer a way to do this without iTunes.